# Disable trigger using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server-2012, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc
# Some other example server values are
# server = 'localhost\sqlexpress' # for a named instance
# server = 'myserver,port' # to specify an alternate port
server = 'TESTSERVER\TEST'
database = 'TESTDB'
username = 'sa'
password = '5678'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.FA_SCPL ON dbo.BILL;")
```

I am not able to disable triggers using above code.Please help.

Comment: What do you mean you're "not able to"? What happens when you do then?

Comment: It would not disable the dbo.FA_SCPL trigger.

Comment: Perhaps try `conn.autocommit = True` immediately after connecting.

Comment: conn.autocommit = True worked for me.Thanks